# Why can't I solve the following integral $\int \frac{\cos x}{5\sin x -3}\mathrm dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried using U-substitution to solve this but it didn't work. I set $u = \sin(x)$ and $\mathrm du = \cos(x)\mathrm dx$. I get $\int  \frac{\mathrm du}{5u-3}$. I get my final answer as $\ln(5\sin(x)-3)$. To be clear, I understand that setting $u = 5\sin(x)-3$ is another way of solving it. I am trying to understand why is it that U-substitution isn't working in this case. I am new integration to apologies for any mistakes.

Comment: Your u-sub is correct. However, your integration of 1/(5u-3) is off by a factor of 5.

Comment: Or if you're not following dan's comment - try (the alternative substitution) $u = 5 \sin x -3$.

Comment: @dan Once I get $\int  \frac{\mathrm du}{5u-3}$, I simplify to $\int (5u-3)^-1$. Wouldn't the anti-derivative of that be $ln(|5u-3|)$?

Comment: No, it would be $\frac{1}{5}\ln\lvert 5u-3\rvert$. Try to differentiate it and see that a factor of $5$ jumps out from the inner derivative

Comment: @Lorago, apologies, I am still unable to see where the $1/5$ comes from.

Comment: @Voltagecrayon24 the $\frac{1}{5}$ comes from when one sets $t = 5u - 3$. Then the $dt = 5du$ requires another 5, so we multiply by a $\frac{1}{5}$ to not change the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from your comment to the post, it seems your issue stems from finding an antiderivative of

$$f(u)=\frac{1}{5u-3}.$$

For simplicity we suppose $u\in[-1,1]$, as that's the situation in your problems. An antiderivative of this would be

$$F(u)=\frac{1}{5}\ln(5u-3),$$

because if we differentiate it we get

$$F'(u)=\frac{1}{5}\cdot 5\cdot\frac{1}{5u-3}=\frac{1}{5u-3}=f(u),$$

where the factor of $5$ is the derivative of $5u-3$, i.e. the inner derivative we also have to respect. What you have to remember is that the chain rule gives rise to this factor of $5$ appearing when we differentiate, and so to compensate for that we need a factor of $\frac{1}{5}$ in the antiderivative. This can also be seen by making, for example, the substitution $t=5u-3$, $\mathrm{d}t=5~\mathrm{d}u$ in the indefinite integral

$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{5u-3}=\frac{1}{5}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t},$$

or simply by rewriting

$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{5u-3}=\frac{1}{5}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u-\frac{3}{5}}=\frac{1}{5}\ln\left\lvert u-\frac{3}{5}\right\rvert+C=\frac{1}{5}\ln\lvert 5u-3\rvert+\frac{1}{5}\ln \frac{1}{5}+C=\frac{1}{5}\ln\lvert 5u-3\rvert+D.$$

Answer (score 0):

Just as a $u$ sub of

$u = 5\sin(x) - 3$ will send you looking for a function whose derivative is

[scalar] $~\times \dfrac{du}{u}$,

a $u$ sub of

$u = 5\sin(x)$ will send you looking for a function whose derivative is

[scalar] $~\times \dfrac{du}{u - 3}.$